# How to loop on javascript urlfor() on Slim + Twig

Tags: javascript, twig, slim

```
{% block page_scripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "all-users-json",
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            var url = "{{ urlFor('management.user', , {'user': "+aData[1]+"}) }}"; //<-----------
            $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<a href="' + url + '">' + aData[0] + '</a>');
        }
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: Look at FOSJsRoutingBundle : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: @PerroinThibault, he is not using Symfony and this bundle will not help him.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov Why does the user set the Symfony tag so ?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov My bad I did not see slim ! agreed Yenne Info

Comment: I removed this tag to not confuse others:-)

Comment: Maybe the user use symfony.... How can you be sure ? In this case, FOSJS Bundle could be interessant

Comment: If he use Symfony he will have another problem. This problem is related to Slim framework. He can't process one request in Slim and Symfony frameworks both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I've just use like this, I've added `user/`

`$('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<a href="user/' + aData[1] + '">' + aData[0] + '</a>');`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html) to generate link for the route you need `path_for()` function instead of `urlFor()`.

Also you are trying to render twig-part in a JS function. Twig renders this block only once. It renders the JS code, not run this code and so it cannot render itself in JS function.

Try this code:

```
{% block page_scripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "all-users-json",
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            {% set pattern = '#some_unique_symbols_combination#' %}
            var url = "{{ path_for('management.user', {'user': pattern}) }}";
            url = url.replace('{{ pattern }}', aData[1]);
            $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<a href="' + url + '">' + aData[0] + '</a>');
        }
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

What happens here? I declared some `pattern` that will not intersect with `aData[1]` values and generated the unique URL for given route. This URL is generated once while Twig renders the page. After that it generates JS line where JS interpreter replace declared `pattern` with JS value passed as argument to the JS function.

Comment: nvm, I've just do like this `$('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<a href=user/"' + aData[1]+ '">' + aData[0] + '</a>');`

Comment: Did you ever try my solution? Your code needs modifying every time you change your route path.

Comment: Note:Slim 3 Documentation: urlFor() has been renamed pathFor() and can be found in the router object:

Answer (score 0):

For Slim 2 i use the solution from Michael (but using urlFor because pathFor not exists in this version)

```js
render:function(data,type,full) {
  let url = "{{ urlFor('archivo.documento.detalle', {'id': "id"}) }}";
  url = url.replace('id',data);
  return '<a href="'+url+'" class="btn btn-info" title="Editar"><i class="bi bi-pencil"></i></a>';
}
```